# How to refactor this code with static init variables?

Tags: swift

I have a static class like this:

```
class CDService {
 static var initVar:Type?
 static var var2:Type2? = { 
    return initVar?.someProp
 }
 static func method() {
  var2?.doSomething()
 }
 //....a lot more methods all using var2?
}
```

Because initVar is optional (require the user to set it before using this service), now var2 has to be optional too.

And then all the methods in this class all of a sudden requires unwrapping. They are use a lot.

Is there a way to refactor this code to just not run if initVar is not yet? I could do a "if let" check in each method but its really tedious. If there is 50 methods?

Answer (score 0):

You can use optional extensions to give default values , I've tried, it's comes really handy when using default datatype optionals.

```
    extension Optional where Wrapped == String { // same goes for other data types
    var orEmpty: String {
        return self ?? ""
    }

    var orDash: String {
        return self ?? "-"
    }

    var orZero: String {
        return self ?? "0"
    }
}
```

or in your case

```
    extension Optional where Wrapped == Type2 {
    var orEmpty: Type2 {
        return self ?? Type2()
    }
}
```